# Ajax request from PHP don't return me an Array

Tags: php, sql, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to return an array from a PHP script in Ajax, however, it seems to not work, it returns me a string rather an Array. I'm using CodeIgniter Framework, there is my .php code :

```
    public function get_form(){

       $donneesModel = new Mdonnees();
       $result = $donneesModel->getAll();

       $data=array(
         'chartDate' => array(),
         'chartTemp' => array(),
       );

       foreach ($result as $row) {
         $data['chartDate'][] = date("d/m", strtotime($row['date']));
         $data['chartTemp'][] = $row['temperature'];
       }

       print json_encode($data);
     }
```

And there is my Ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
url:"Cdonnees/get_form",
method:"GET",
success:function(data)  {
console.log(data);
....
....
}
```

My getAll() function just select all from the database, however i'm only using the temperature & date column.

It should return me an Array like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx8sG.png),
But rather it returns me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8o17.png).

Can you please help me or give me some clue of what is going on ?

Yours sincerely,.

Comment: please don't post images of code, error messages or other like variables, etc. Add them as code-formatted text instead, since none of us can copy, paste and run an image. For more on this, please see why we 
[**Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2275490)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON in Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"Cdonnees/get_form",
    method:"GET",
    success:function(data)  {
       //this will print the data
       console.log(JSON.parse(data));
       // save it to a variable and can use it in the rest of the program
       const pareseData = JSON.parse(data);
       ....
       ....
    }
 });
```

and it should work.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
It appers well in the console.log, however now how can i parse it for all the script? Thanks :)

Comment: @juststartedcodeigniter what do you mean by parsing for the whole script?

Comment: As you can see here [link](https://prnt.sc/26ghdl6) : my results don't show up on my graph and when i put a console.log(data) before and after the parse, the result in my console is still the same : [link](https://prnt.sc/26ghe2l) as you can see here too :-)

Comment: @juststartedcodeigniter It was a good practice if you share all of your code in the `success` function. whatever I update the answer that might be fixed your problem. just use the `pareseData` in the rest of the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
        url:"Cdonnees/get_form",
        method:"GET",
        success:function(data)  {
            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                  console.log(key)
                  console.log(value)
            })
         }
    });
```

Comment: or simply: console.dir(data)